# I want to set simpledate values so I can compare them to get an age

Tags: java, input, simpledateformat

How would I set `dateBirth` and `dateToday` to equal the values that I enter in a mm/dd/yyyy format?

```
public class AgeClientFL {

public static void main(String [] args){

  int month, day, year;

  day = UtilsFL.readInt("Enter birth day: ",false); // String mode
  month = UtilsFL.readInt("Enter birth month: ",false);
  year = UtilsFL.readInt("Enter birth year: ",false);

  SimpleDate dateBirth = new SimpleDate();

  day = UtilsFL.readInt("Enter todays day: ",true); // JOptionPane mode
  month = UtilsFL.readInt("Enter todays month: ",true);
  year = UtilsFL.readInt("Enter todays year: ",true);

  SimpleDate dateToday = new SimpleDate();




   }
}
```

Comment: There is no class `SimpleData` in Java by default.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation/source code for your SimpleDate class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

...

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date date = sdf.parse(dateString);
System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```

However, this `java.util.Date` isn't really useful, everything is deprecated you can only use getTime(). The <strike>`java.sql.Date`</strike> `java.util.GregorianCalendar` is much more useful. I would have a look into that, you can easily get years, month, days etc. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html